# How to get the answer for exponents questions

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, exponential

I'm new to python. I'm also a beginner on this subject. So any help would be great!

I'm trying to write a code for calculating the answer for questions like 3^2 = 9 , 2^3 = 8, etc.

I know there is a ** for this. But I need to use while loops and for loops for this.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and what I need for these loops. I also need the loop to tell the user it's the wrong answer if they enter in a number less than zero. I need to know how it would start the loop from the beginning again if they inputted the wrong answer. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is what I have so far:

```
base1 = int(input("Base:"))
base2 = 1
exponent = int(input("Exponent:"))
ExpNeeded = True
while ExpNeeded: 
    for hat in range(exponent): 
        base2 = base2 * base1
        print("Answer:" , base2)

    ExpNeeded = False


else:
    print("Please enter a number greater than zero")
```

Answer (score 0):

i used your code also you  can use `while` without ExpNeeded and `break` loop(`while`) i.e `while True:`

```
ExpNeeded = True
while ExpNeeded :
    base2 = 1
    base1=int(input("Base:"))
    while base1<=0:
        print "Please enter a number greater than zero"
        base1=int(input("Base:"))
    exponent=int(input("Exponent:"))
    while exponent<=0:
        print "Please enter a number greater than zero"
        exponent=int(input("exponent:"))
    for hat in range(exponent): 
        base2 = base2 * base1
    print 'answer: ' , base2
    print "to repeat press 1 else press 0"
    if int(input(" "))==1:
        pass
    else:
        ExpNeeded =False
```

output:

```
Base:2
Exponent:5
answer:  32
to repeat press 1 else press 0
 1
Base:-2
Please enter a number greater than zero
Base:6
Exponent:2
answer:  36
to repeat press 1 else press 0
 0
```

Comment: The `while :` should probably be `while True:`

Comment: @martineau yeah i mentioned this at the top of answer  `i used your code also you can use while without ExpNeeded and break loop(while)`i meant this `while True:`

Comment: Regardless, since you show output following the code in your answer, it seems to imply that the invalid code shown in it might actually run (instead of producing a `SyntaxError`).

Comment: @martineau  should i edit answer to the proper answer

Comment: @martineau i missed it  i am sorry

Comment: Thank you everyone! This is very helpful!

Comment: base = 0     exponent = 1

Comment: @Vivi variable declartion only to use them inside loop you can make both equal 0 or 1

Comment: @Vivi removed from answer. i am sorry

Comment: @HishamKaram don't worry about it! I was just a bit confused. Thanks for clarifying! You're awesome!